# How to wrap text inside fixed length dropdown item in Reactstrap?

Tags: dropdown, word-wrap, reactstrap

In my Reactstrap dropdown, I want the dropdown menu to have a fixed length and text be wrapped inside dropdown menu item. How can I do that? The below shows the current code and it's result.

[image]

```js
<DropdownMenu right style={{position: "absolute"}}>
                <DropdownItem style={{maxWidth: "30vw",wordWrap: "break-word"}}>
kdddddddd  ddddddddd dddddddd ddd ddddddddddddd dddd dddddd dddddddd mmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>

                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: Try adding `whitespace: pre-wrap`.